# Products not showing in catalog after media migration from magento 1.9 to 2.1

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-2.1, migration, media-images

I just migrated my site from magento 1.9.2 to magento 2.1.5. The problem started after I copied the media folder. All the images showed, but all of the products in catalog and search disappeared - So I reindexed and flushed the cache but the products are still not showing (they were before the media folder copy) and if I go directly to a product url everything shows normally. Anyone knows what it could be?

Comment: Any error you are facing? How did you updated database?What you got in Inspect element?

Comment: Are product displaying in admin panel?

Comment: There is no error it is just empty ( http://89.212.55.124:88/ ).. I migrated the data using data-migration-tool. Everything was ok after migration, products where showing normally, but when I copied the media the products disappeared in search and catalog but the filters show the number of products besides them. If I go directly to the product link it shows normally (http://89.212.55.124:88/izdelava-nakita/osnove-za-nakit/za-uhane/lisa-pavelka-osnova-za-uhane-9157)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using theme porto and for some reason after I imported one of their demos products showed normally..